# Changing redirect_uri in facebook app

Tags: facebook, meteor, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication

I am not sure what property sets the redirect_uri url that appears in the popup facebook dialogue box when authenticating via facebook. I'm asking this because I would like to change it but all attempts have failed. Is this url set from the facebook app settings ( maybe from the site url) or does it need to be changed in JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you use the Meteor `accounts-facebook` package, this URL is defined for you and is of the form: `<your-site-url>/_oauth/facebook/?close`

You need to set this URL in your Facebook App page under

Settings -> Advanced -> Client OAuth settings -> Valid OAuth redirect URIs

Answer (score 0):

Check on my image[image]

Here is your rout `Settings > Advanced > Client OAuth settings > Valid OAuth redirect URIs`